# How to add many things to array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to add about 30'000 filenames to an array.
How could i do that?

Currently it's just printing them in console:

```
File folder = new File("D:\\image");
    File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listofFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listofFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File "+listofFiles[i].getName());
        }else if (listofFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory "+listofFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You already have an array of Files. What is the goal? Maybe use folder.list() instead of folder.listFiles()

Comment: `array[i++] = thing;`

Comment: The operative word is `about`.  Use an `ArrayList<File>` and you don't have to worry about how many files there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new list and put into it names of files

```
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
File folder = new File("D:\\image");
File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listofFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listofFiles[i].isFile()) {
            fileNames.add(listofFiles[i].getName());

            System.out.println("File "+listofFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listofFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory "+listofFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

Will be good to use streams here but I believe this solution will be more clear for you. After that you can convert list to array by: `String[] fileNamesArray = fileNames.toArray(new String[0]);`

---